# Compiling with Cmake on Docker, getting broken compiler for gcc

Tags: c, docker, gcc, cmake

I am trying to build a docker image to run a C++ program, but have not been able to compile as I've been getting the following error.

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:52 (message):
  The C compiler

    "/usr/bin/cc"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /app/cgal/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command:"/app/cgal/make" "cmTC_d157a/fast"
    /app/cgal/make: 1: /app/cgal/make: ifndef: not found
    /app/cgal/make: 2: /app/cgal/make: CGAL_MAKEFILE: not found
: not foundal/make: 3: /app/cgal/make: endif
    /app/cgal/make: 4: /app/cgal/make: CGAL_MAKEFILE: not found
    /app/cgal/make: 4: /app/cgal/make: include: not found
: not foundal/make: 5: /app/cgal/make:
    /app/cgal/make: 6: /app/cgal/make: LIBPATH: not found
    /app/cgal/make: 7: /app/cgal/make: CGAL_LIBPATH: not found
: not foundal/make: 7: /app/cgal/make:
: not foundal/make: 8: /app/cgal/make:
    /app/cgal/make: 9: /app/cgal/make: LDFLAGS: not found
    /app/cgal/make: 10: /app/cgal/make: LONG_NAME_PROBLEM_LDFLAGS: not found
: not foundal/make: 10: /app/cgal/make:
    /app/cgal/make: 11: /app/cgal/make: CGAL_LDFLAGS: not found
: not foundal/make: 11: /app/cgal/make:
: not foundal/make: 12: /app/cgal/make:
    /app/cgal/make: 13: /app/cgal/make: LIBPATH: not found
    /app/cgal/make: 13: /app/cgal/make: LDFLAGS: not found
    /app/cgal/make: 13: /app/cgal/make: -fopenmp: not found
: not foundal/make: 15: /app/cgal/make:
    /app/cgal/make: 16: /app/cgal/make: all:: not found
    /app/cgal/make: 17: /app/cgal/make: EXEC: not found
    /app/cgal/make: 17: /app/cgal/make: COMP: not found
    g++: error: main.o: No such file or directory
: No such file or directory
    g++: fatal error: no input files
    compilation terminated.
: not foundal/make: 18: /app/cgal/make:
    /app/cgal/make: 19: /app/cgal/make: main.o:: not found
    /app/cgal/make: 20: /app/cgal/make: COMP: not found
    g++: fatal error: no input files
    compilation terminated.




  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:8 (project)
```

I inspected the docker container I was running and found the path for C_COMPILER as `/usr/lib/cc/gcc` and then tried force setting the compiler in my `CMakeLists.txt` using `set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/usr/lib/cc/gcc")`,  but it returned the following error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:8 (project):
  The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

    /usr/lib/cc/gcc

  is not a full path to an existing compiler tool.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
  the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.
```

I am not sure where the problem lies, and I do not have much experience with docker. Any help would be appreciated.

For reference, this is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    cmake \
    build-essential \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libcgal-dev
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app/cgal/
RUN cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release .
RUN make
```

Comment: `I inspected the docker container I was running and found the path for C_COMPILER as /usr/lib/cc/gcc` How exactly did you get this path? `It fails with the following output:` Whats the output after that line?

Comment: @tkausl I went to the container that was running the image on Docker desktop -> Inspect -> C_COMPILER, it showed the path as `/usr/lib/cc/gcc`. I've updated the question to show the entire output error message.

Comment: `COPY . /app` Is you `.` directory clean? As in no build or generated files whatsoever. `WORKDIR /app/cgal/` if you only need `cgal` dir, why are you copying everything? The error most probably comes from not-clean build directory and you being on windows  and using stale files.

Comment: @KamilCuk, updated the Dockerfile to copy only cgal folder (`COPY cgal/ /app/cgal/`), and tried running a clean build, but still running into the same issue. What do you mean by using stale files? Is it not possible to run this on windows?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are compiling a C++ file you'd probably want to set `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` rather than `CMAKE_C_COMPILER`. I don't believe that either is strictly necessary because the default compiler should be 100% fine.

```
├── cgal
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── hello-world.cpp
└── Dockerfile
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    cmake \
    build-essential \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libcgal-dev

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app/cgal/

RUN cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release .
RUN make
```

`cgal/hello-world.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

`cgal/CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/usr/bin/gcc")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/bin/g++")

project(HelloWorld)

add_executable(HelloWorld hello-world.cpp)
```

[image]